# How to ignore \n\t when AJAX reading a text file?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I can use the AJAX call to read a text file, but the problem is it read the \n\t, and the symbol '\' (Backslash), it is not necessary for me, How can I ignore it to pure text msg....?

Comment: When do you want to ignore them ? When you print it ?  When you process it ? I think that you need to remove it after reading.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better. You want to do what exactly with newlines, tabs, and literal slash characters?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
text = text.replace (/\s+/g, " ")
text = text.replace (/\\'/g, "'")
```

Comment: that's nice, I want to ignore the  "\" too, how can I do it?